# Convert any type of an image to PNG and add to PNG

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am trying to create an employee poster for a website that I develop. My goal is to take an image from a directory on the server of any file type (.png, .gif, .jpeg, etc.) and copy it onto another generate imaged that will then be outputted to the browser.

The problem is that I use:

`$final_image = imagecreatefrompng("large_background.png");`

for making the final image and for some reason if I add profile images with the type jpeg's, gif's, etc, (any type that isn't a jpeg) it doesn't work. The images never show up in the output. However, if I use png's it does work.

To solve this problem I tried converting the image to a png and then creating a png from it as shown in the code below. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Profile images still do not show up on the background.

```
// get image from database 
$image_from_database = could be a .png, .jpeg, .gif, etc.

// get the image from the profile images directory
$path = "profile_images/".$image_from_database;

// create a png out of the image
$image = imagecreatefrompng(imagepng($path));

// add the $image to my larger $final_image (which is a png)
imagecopy($final_image, $image, $x, $y, 0,0, $height, $width);
imagepng($final_image, $ouput_url);
...
```

Can anybody tell me why this won't work? My profile images do not show up in the output of the final image.

My questions,

- Is this line `imagecreatefrompng(imagepng(...));` even possible? Essentially I want to convert an image of any type into a png and then create a png from it.

Comment: [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) [`imagecreatefromgif`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)

Comment: As I said, if I do this it does not appear when I `imagecopy` it onto the png.

Comment: Did you read what [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) expects as arguments and what it returns? Or what it's actually doing?

Comment: So are you proposing: `$image = imagecreatefrompng(imagepng(imagecreatefromjpeg($path)));`?

Comment: `$image = imagecreatefrompng($path);` for png images, `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);` for jpeg images and `$image = imagecreatefromgif($path);` for gif images.

Comment: I understand that. But if I `imagecopy` a jpeg/gif onto my background png it doesn't work. The images do not show up. If I use `imagecreatefrompng` it's fine of course, but not for other types.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just running a few local tests... The following works:

```
$src = imagecreatefromgif('test.gif');
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('test.png');

imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($dest);
```

So does this:

```
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('test.gif'));
```

If you're still having trouble after trying the latter example, please update your question. The actual images you're using would be helpful, in addition to a functional code example.

Comment: Can you try it with a jpeg? I find that this doesn't work when using a jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

After you read an image with a `imagecreatefrom*` function, it doesn't matter what format the original was.
`imagecreatefrom*` functions return an image resource. When the image is loaded you are using internal representation of the images and not PNG, JPEG or GIF images.
If the images are successfully loaded `imagecopy` should have no problems with them.

This code uses images in different formats and works without a problem:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('bg.png');
$png_img = imagecreatefrompng('img.png');
$jpeg_img = imagecreatefromjpeg('img.jpeg');
$gif_img = imagecreatefromgif('img.gif');

/* or use this, so you don't need to figure out which imagecreatefrom* function to use
$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('bg.png'));
$png_img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('img.png'));
$jpeg_img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('img.jpeg'));
$gif_img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('img.gif'));
*/
imagecopyresampled($img, $png_img,   10, 10, 0,0, 100, 100, 200, 200);
imagecopyresampled($img, $jpeg_img, 120, 10, 0,0, 100, 100, 200, 200);
imagecopyresampled($img, $gif_img,  230, 10, 0,0, 100, 100, 200, 200);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
```

Your example

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng(imagepng($path));
```

is wrong.
`imagepng` is used to output an image resource as a PNG image. If you provide a path as a second argument a PNG image file is created, otherwise it's printed to the output like `echo` does.
What `imagepng` actually returns is a boolean, indicating, if the output was successful.
You are then passing that boolean to `imagecreatefrompng` which expects a filepath. This is obviously wrong.

I suspect you have a problem with loading images.
`imagecreatefrom*` functions return `FALSE` on failure and you should check, if you have any problems with that.

Maybe your image paths are relative to doc root and your working directory is different.
Or you have permission problem.
Or your images are just missing.
It's impossible to tell from your question.